# Tensorflow - Dealing with images that can NOT be classified

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am experimenting with a tensorflow to filter images. Specifically I want to look for certain elements that are NSFW and filter those while allowing others to be uploaded.

When I retrain and use the example: https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining

It works as expected on a NSFW image but when I throw a random image in it it always try to guess what one of the 4 it might be. No matter how many different images I throw at it that don't contain any object it can classify it will always say one of the four is at least .8 even if the image does not contain something it's been trained with.

I'm not sure if i'm lacking training images (i have about 200 to train it with for each of the 4 categories im checking) currently I know it would be better with more. Or if the example *label_image.py* will always attempt to classify with one of the categories its trained with.

Is it possible to tweak the *label_image.py* so that I can put a "false" image into it it simply give low probability?

Comment: The classifier is always going to try to assign the input to one of the classes you have trained it on. You need to have a classification that is "not NSFW" and train it with examples that are "not NSFW", which is a large set. 200 images is almost certainly too small. A rule of thumb is that you are going to need about 1000 images per class.

Comment: Yea thats what I was worried about, when an image can be anything BUT NSFW I don't even know how I begin to train for that